# Returning function arguments from assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

I'm using an AMD 64bit (I don't think it matters what exact architecture) on Linux, also 64bit. Compiling with gcc to elf64.

I've seen from the C ABI that integer arguments are passed to a function via general purpose registers, and I can find the values on the assembly side of my code (the callee). The problem arises when I need to retrieve the results from the callee to the caller.

As far as I can understand, RAX gets the 1st integer *returned* value, and I can easily find and use that one. The 2nd integer *returned* value is passed via RDX. And this is the point that baffles me.

I can also see, from the C ABI, that RDX is the register used to pass the third integer function argument from the caller to the callee, but my function doesn't use a third argument.

How do I get the RDX out from my function? Do I have to fake an argument in the function just to be able to refer to it on the caller side?

---

fixed point multiplication 16.16:

called from C looks like:

```
typedef long int Fixedpoint;
Fixedpoint _FixedMul(Fixedpoint v1, Fixedpoint v2);
```

and this is the function itself:

```
_FixedMul:
   push bp
   mov bp, sp
; entering the function EDI contains v1, ESI contains v2. So:
   mov eax, edi   ; eax = v1
   imul dword esi ; eax = v1 * v2
                  ; at this point EDX contains the higher part of the
                  ; imul moltiplication, EAX the lower one.
   add eax, 8000h ; round by adding 2^(-17)
   adc edx, 0     ; whole part of result is in DX
   shr eax, 16    ; put the fractional part in AX
   pop bp
   ret
```

from [System V Application Binary Interface
AMD64 Architecture Processor Supplement](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf)

> Returning of Values algorithm:
>
> The returning of values is done according to the following
>
> 1. Classify the return type with the classification algorithm.
> 2. If the type has class MEMORY, then the caller provides space for the return
>      value and passes the address of this storage in %rdi as if it were the first
>      argument to the function. In effect, this address becomes a “hidden” first ar-
>      gument. This storage must not overlap any data visible to the callee through
>      other names than this argument.
>      On return %rax will contain the address that has been passed in by the
>      caller in %rdi.
> 3. If the class is INTEGER, the next available register of the sequence %rax,
>      %rdx is used.

I hope is more clear what i mean.

PS: sorry for confusion I've made in comments. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Only 1 result can be returned, and that's in `rax` or `xmm0` or in memory depending on the type.

Comment: Your English is absolutely fine. And how arguments are passed depends on the calling convention that has been adopted. Actual return values are returned in `(E/R)AX`; however, if the function receives some pointers to "return" more values, those pointers will be passed as normal arguments (usually on the stack, in `__stdcall` and `__cdecl`, which are most common).

Comment: I think i need to past a snippet from http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf:

Comment: I think I need to add paste a snippet from (http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf)

3.2.3
Parameter Passing

Returning of Values
algorithm:
The returning of values is done according to the following
2. If the type has class MEMORY, then the caller provides space for the return value and passes the address of this storage in %rdi as if it were the first argument to the function.[...cut...]
On return %rax will contain the address that has been passed in by the
caller in %rdi.

Comment: sorry, I'm still trying to understand how to comment... :)

Comment: 3. If the class is INTEGER, the next available register of the sequence rax, %rdx is used.

Comment: '; typedef long int Fixedpoint
; Fixedpoint FixedMul(Fixedpoint v1, Fixedpoint v2);
_FixedMul:
  push bp
  mov bp, sp
  mov eax, edi   ; eax = v1
  imul dword esi ; eax = v1 * v2
  add eax, 8000h ; round by adding 2^(-17)
  adc edx, 0     ; whole part of result is in DX
  shr eax, 16    ; put the fractional part in AX
  pop bp
  ret
'

Comment: I'm really sorry. I can't even add some code. :| Anyway, after the "imult", edx will have the upper part of the multiplication (the integer part), and eax the fractional part. What I need is to get edx out of my function, and i thought it was possible via the registers mechanism. Maybe I've got it all wrong.

Comment: Please don't. You can use [edit] to add important information to your question. Make sure to write it as if it is **part of the question**, so don't add 'Edit' or 'answer to @...'. You can delete your previous comments when done. (As a new user, you also may want to read the introductory [tour] some time.)

Comment: @Jongware Okay, done ;)

Comment: @szczurcio: unfortunately it seems OP does not *want* `eax` but needs  `edx` from his routine (and only that). Which would make the question being about about a specific ABI more or less redundant. We'll have to await the edit.

Comment: Since you're trying to optimize for speed, keep in mind that on "normal" (Intel/AMD) x86 CPUs, fixed-point math takes more instructions, enough to make it slower than just using the powerful hardware floating point.  Also, on amd64, you need to push/pop `rbp`, not just the low 16 bits!  If you're not spilling any local variables to memory on the stack, don't even bother creating a stack frame by saving `rsp`.

Comment: Also, if you want to do a 64bit multiply, use 64bit registers.  Then you won't need add-with-cary.  Maybe it works better for the rest of your functions to carry around your fixed-point data in two parts.

Answer (score 3):

The [AMD64 calling conventions (System V ABI)](https://uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf) designate a dual-use role for register RDX: it may be used to pass the third argument (if any) **and** it may be used as second return register. (cf. Figure 3.4, page 21)

Depending on the function signature it's used for either or none of these roles.

So why are there 2 return registers (i.e. RAX and RDX)? This allows a function to return values of up to 128 bits in general purpose registers - such as `__int128` or a `struct` with two 8 byte fields.

Thus, to access the RDX register from your C call site you just have to adjust your function's signature. That means instead of

```
typedef long int Fixedpoint;
Fixedpoint _FixedMul(Fixedpoint v1, Fixedpoint v2);
```

declare it as:

```
typedef long int Fixedpoint;
struct Fixedpoint_Pair { // when used as return value:
    Fixedpoint fst;      //   - passed in RAX
    Fixedpoint snd;      //   - passed in RDX
};
typedef struct Fixedpoint_Pair Fixedpoint_Pair;

Fixedpoint_Pair _FixedMul(Fixedpoint v1, Fixedpoint v2);
```

Then you can access RDX like this in your C code:

```
Fixedpoint_Pair r = _FixedMul(a, b);
printf("RDX: %ld\n", r.snd);
```

References:

- page 18,19: especially 'The classification of aggregate (structure and arrays)', point 3:

> If the size of the aggregate exceeds a single eightbyte, each is classified
>   separately. Each eightbyte gets initialized to class NO_CLASS.

- page 22: 'Return of Values', point 3:

> If the class is INTEGER, the next available register of the sequence %rax,
>   %rdx is used.

Comment: Perhaps worth pointing out that the OP's asm doesn't match their function signature: it only uses the low 32 bits of each 64-bit `long`.  And also for some insane reason saves/restores `bp` (but not the full RBP).  Or not; I did leave a comment about that under the question already.

Comment: @PeterCordes, at least the upper 32 bit are zero-extended and thus the function signature is compatible. But sure, as is, OP's code in the function body doesn't make much sense. Arguably, the concrete body isn't even relevant to the question, really. I saw your comments and I upvoted them. :)

Comment: Ya, it doesn't cause UB or a calling convention mismatch, and will work for small inputs.  The opposite problem is potentially worse; assuming function args are zero-extended to 64-bit when they actually can contain high garbage that your caller was counting on you to ignore.  (Unlike some RISC ABIs, x86-64 System V allows high garbage because every instruction is available with (almost) every operand-size.  Except clang relies on narrow args being zero- or sign-extended to 32-bit, and GCC also implements that unofficial behaviour in callers, but doesn't depend on it in callees.)

Answer (score 1):

Your English is absolutely fine.

How arguments are passed depends on the calling convention that has been adopted - the two most common ones, `__stdcall` and `__cdecl`, use the stack to pass all arguments, but for example the `__fastcall` convention will use registers for the first two args, and in x64, it's still different. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_fastcall) for a comprehensive list.

Actual return values are returned in `(E/R)AX`; however, if the function receives some pointers to "return" more values, those pointers will be passed as normal arguments - as previously stated, usually on the stack.

Comment: I see. The point is that I am trying to optimize for speed, so the less memory movement is involved, the better. I could "SHL EDX,16" and "OR EAX,EDX" to get the complete result on EAX or simply move EDX on ESI to get it on v2, or something in that flavour. But there's no way out: rAX is the only one "real" output register. My bad, I completely misunderstood the ABI. :) Thanks for your answer(s).